# asp.net mvc selectlist - field to dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a web service response of type AutomatOwners[] where AutomatOwners consists of two fields ID and Name. I would like to create a select list and then present it as dropdownlist, where Name would be displayed as an option and ID would be its option value.
My idea was something like this:

```
ViewData["automat_owners"] = new SelectList((AutomatOwners[])web_service_response);
```

and in the view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("Owner", (SelectList)ViewData["automat_owners"]) %>
```

but obviously that is not enough. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ViewData["automat_owners"] = new SelectList(web_service_response as IEnumerable, "ID", "Name");
```